# do fit function of QSVC require float values as parameters?

Tags: python, machine-learning, quantum-computing, qiskit

Following is my code. The error seems to be in qsvc.fit() line but I can't understand why.one of the error line says "TypeError: Invalid parameter values, expected Sequence[Sequence[float]]." I'm pretty much sure I have passed arrays as parameters in fit function but do they need to be float type because labels are generally strings. sorry this is my first time trying this so these may seem naive.

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
from qiskit import Aer
from qiskit.circuit.library import ZFeatureMap
from qiskit_machine_learning.kernels import FidelityQuantumKernel
from qiskit.algorithms.state_fidelities import ComputeUncompute
from qiskit.primitives import Sampler
from qiskit.utils import QuantumInstance
from qiskit_machine_learning.algorithms import PegasosQSVC

data=pd.read_csv('train.csv')
X = data.loc[1:1000,["marital","balance","loan"]].values
Y = data.iloc[:1000,-1].values
x_train, x_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, Y)
data_feature_map = ZFeatureMap(feature_dimension=3, reps=1 )
sampler = Sampler()
fidelity = ComputeUncompute(sampler=sampler)
data_kernel = FidelityQuantumKernel(fidelity=fidelity, feature_map=data_feature_map)
pegasos_qsvc = PegasosQSVC(quantum_kernel=data_kernel, C=1000, num_steps=100)
pegasos_qsvc.fit(x_train, y_train)
qsvc_score = pegasos_qsvc.score(x_test, y_test)

print(f"QSVC classification test score: {qsvc_score}")
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use values 0,1 and 2 to represent "marital", "balance" and "loan". sklearn has a LabelEncoder to help such a conversion.

Comment: I don't think problem lies there but. the values of those columns are still float type

Comment: There is a tutorial for PegasosSVC here - https://qiskit.org/documentation/machine-learning/tutorials/07_pegasos_qsvc.html Maybe comparing what it passes in versus what you do?